# Digital signal from mark sensor to software event

Tags: digital-logic

Disclaimer: I don't know much about electronics yet, so please excuse a beginner question.

I have a software that needs to send data by TCP/IP and briefly trigger an output, when a photo sensor (black mark reader) is triggered. So the chain of events would be:

```
black mark read => signal to input => sofware sends data via TCP/IP => trigger output
```

I have the data transfer and output in place, using a simple [DLP/IO8](https://www.dlpdesign.com/DNLD8/).   The sensor I use is a Datalogic TL46 (NPN), but I have access to others.

While I **can** constantly poll the DLP/IO8 for an input, I fear that it would not be near real-time. The polling is by RS232 on that device.

Speedwise, I am looking at 100 msec intervals as the minimum.

So given that my setup for now is:

- Software written in Delphi
- A Windows PC
- A mark reader
- Need for 1 input and 1 output (minimum)
- Near real time, if possible
- Reasonable money to spend, does not have to be free

What direction should I go ? I have been considering a PCIex I/O card, but don't know if that would be overkill.

Arduino is not the way to go this time because I need the software part.

If the DLP/IO is realtime enough to be used, that could also be an alternative.

Comment: I've no idea about the DLP/IO8, except what I quickly read on that linked page. There, it seems to say that with their own drivers in place the device will detect signal changes and emulate a key-press. That's it, from what I see there. You, on the other hand, have failed to define `real-time` in your context. Yes, key emulation in Windows is usually a slow process using inter-process remote procedure calls packaged up as messages eventually sent into a process (with a window handle.) Also, what you need to do for output is ??? I know you say it works. But I don't know `how' it is done.

Comment: @periblepsis you are correct, information not detailed. I receive the photo sensor signal (this is where I need guidance), then send some data via TCP/IP, and then send a an output signal which will trigger a solid state relay for about 20 msec. `real-time` in this case is "as good as I can get it". The parts being triggered moves about 1-3 meter/second (60-180 m/min). So a delay / variation of 5-10 msec is not critical.   DLP/8 is operated by sending a character by RS232 from the PC, to ask for state of input, or to set output.

Comment: You will need to completely avoid the DLP/IO8 if you want things as good as you can get them. I'd junk it. You cannot go through Windows keystroke emulation as a step in the process leading to the SSR. ***Especially*** if you like 5-10 milliseconds for the loop delay. I would also recommend sending out the TCP/IP data ***in parallel*** with the step that triggers the SSR. The TCP/IP should be completely decoupled from the sensor-to-SSR process.

Comment: Please be aware that "real time" in engineering says nothing about the tolerable latency. It says that the latency is **guaranteed** to be less than a specific time, which you omit. What you probably mean is "in less than 100 ms most of the time, as a standard PC cannot guarantee that." Is this correct? -- Additionally, "_100 msec intervals as the minimum_" means that intervals shorter than 100 ms are wrong.

Comment: @periblepsis I can't send the TCP/IP in parallel (same time) as the SSR, since the receiving end needs to execute a command based on what I send. The purpose is to simulate an environment, to the best of my ability.

Comment: @MyICQ Then either you need to find your own path out of your maze or else you need to write a lot more about the situation if others are being asked to help. My opinion. I'm leaving this question for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse an existing RS232 port (not the TTL version) for this kind of I/O.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4TXM3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I assume a sensor with positive going edge on detection. The divider R2/R3 will reduce the amplitude to 12 V, which is an acceptable input signal for the RXD input. This RXD input is DC biased from the idle negative TXD via R4 to improve the noise suppression.

The positive edge will produce a (not fully) random character in the serial port, which can be watched as an (WM_CHAR) event on the serial channel.

The used baudrate is not very important, but if chosen too high, the rising edge may introduce 2 or more characters.

The solid state relay can be driven by changing the RTS (or DTR) signal state. The provided current is sufficient for a typical SSR.

Because the inactive RTS signal voltage is negative, D2 is inserted to protect the SSR input from reverse voltages.

If the SSR pulse with needs better timing, the TXD output can be used. Sending a binary zero at 600 baud 8N1 will produce a 15 ms positive pulse.

Comment: Good input. The RS232 library does have an event for "char received". This gives me material to work with. Do you know if this will work via a RS232-USB (prolific chip). ?

Comment: @MyICQ Yes, this works with USB-RS232 converters, but there is a package delay of around 4 ms where the chip waits for more data until it sends an USB data block. This can be configured for true FTDI devices. The output current is a bit lower, expect 3-5 mA. At low baudrates you may need 1 uF as C1.